# DispatchQueue Priority And Thread Analysis ?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, multithreading

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            print("MAIN ASYNC")
        }
        DispatchQueue.global().async {
            print("GLOBAL ASYNC ")
        }
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async {
            print("GLOBAL ASYNC USER INITIATED ")
        }
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .default).async {
            print("GLOBAL ASYNC USER Default ")
        }
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInteractive).async {
            print("GLOBAL ASYNC USER INTERACTIVE")
        }
        DispatchQueue.global().sync {
            print("GLOBAL SYNC ")
        }

    }
```

Result Vary Every time I Run IT

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

So How to know Which thread Run first Or in Which Order They Will Run ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> So How to know Which thread Run first Or in Which Order They Will Run ?

You can't.

The global queue is a concurrent queue, so it will run several tasks in parallel depending on the size of the thread pool. If the pool is big enough to allocate threads to all of your tasks at once, they will all run in parallel and the order in which the print statements appear in the log will be more or less non deterministic.

Note that the one thread you start on the main queue is handled differently. Tasks on the main queue are handled by the run loop which means your asynchronous task cannot start until the current event has finished. If you are in `viewDidLoad` the current event is starting up the application so your main queue task is likely to be delayed a relatively long time. That's why it always appears last in your output.

The qos value will make a difference, but only in resource constrained situations.

**Edit**

Didn't spot the `sync` call when I wrote the answer. Howver, it only changes things minimally. The `sync` block will always run before the `main` block because the `main` block cannot run until the current event has finished which will block until the `sync` call has finished.

Even if GCD prioritises `sync` over `async`, you still cannot tell when it will run because you start all of the `async` calls before the `sync` call. It's entirely possible that they have finished before the `sync` call even starts.

The  same applies to qos. If you schedule a low priority block and then a high priority block, the low priority block can start (and finish) before your main thread even gets to the `async` for the high priority block.

Comment: in global queue sync one should run before async and qos Order are also changing .QOS as Defined User initiative > user Interactive > Default But It is Not Following This Order Also . @JeremyP

Comment: Can We Create Multiple Global Queues . when App Starts A Main Queue Is Made automatically And when we create queues with different QOS So Does It Create Multiple global Queues Or Make Threads With Different Priority In a Single Global Queues ?

Comment: @Amey You don't create global queues. Conceptually, they are singletons that your application has when it starts. I believe (but it doesn't really matter if it is not exactly true) that there is a separate global queue for each QOS value. No queue apart from the main queue has a dedicated thread, they all pick a thread out of a thread pool to execute each task. The main queue executes its tasks on the application's run loop.